# "There has to be" vs "there have to be"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verb-forms

Which form to choose for the verb "have"?

> There have to be other solutions...
> There has to be other solutions...

Somehow, both sound correct. I chose the first one, but isn't the second one also ok? Or does the meaning change somehow? Or does it depend on what follows (singular/plural)?

Comment: The second one is not OK. _Solutions_ is plural, so we say _There are other solutions_ - _There have to be other solutions_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. The first phrase is actually a better choice since the choice of using has/have depends on whether the words following it are singular or plural.  This phrase is an example of existential construction, you can read more details here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/grammar/comments/4355wf/there_has_vs_there_have/